# How to get unique data from response of array and to redirect using react js?

Tags: json, reactjs, arraylist, onclick, response

```
    class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        showItems:[],
        users: []
      }
    }
  
onClick(index){
console.log('its clicked')
let showItems = this.state.showItems.slice(0);
showItems[index] = !showItems[index];
this.setState({showItems});
axios
  .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({ users: response.data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(Error);
    this.setState({ errorMsg: "Wrong API call !!!" });
  });
 }

 handleNest(event){
event.stopPropagation()
console.log('i got a click')
}

 render() {

const { users } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>
      <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this,0)}> item {this.state.showItems[0] ? <div> {users.length
          ? users.map(user => (
              
                <div
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    color: "blue",
                    textTransform: "initial"
                  }}
                  onClick={this.handleNest.bind(this,i)}
                  key={user.id}
                >
                  {user.name}
                </div>
            ))
          : null} </div> : null} </li>
    </ul>
    <div style={{marginTop: 100}}>*click on item to open submenu</div>
  </div>
);}}
   export default App;
```

**MY Question is :**

i want to get the one data which is getting click from that array, like i want to go to some other page with the data selected from array.

**[Attached image -- Here is the output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbRhP.png)** inside of item.. i can get the console by getting click, but i have to know which item is getting click and i have to fetch that for some other page, can anyone help me by suggesting any ideas please ....

Comment: Just being perfectly honest - no clue what you’re asking for.

Comment: You can use react router to redirect to new page and pass the item id with it. In the new page you can use componentDidMount to make a new API call and fetch the required data and display accordingly.

Comment: @ntk Thank you for your response.. :) How to get that item particularly from the array? which is getting clicked. I was trying to get that item id which is getting click , because its also I'm mapping from json's response that's the problem.

Comment: @MercyKannan    onClick={this.handleNest(user.id).bind(this,i)}. And destructure in handleNest accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using React Router DOM.

Update app component as :

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import NewPage from "./NewPage";
import CurrentPage from "./CurrentPage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={CurrentPage} />
          <Route exact path="/newpage/:id" component={NewPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Update the return statement as :

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>
      <li> item {this.state.showItems[0] ? <div> {users.length
          ? users.map(user => (
              
    <Link to={`/newpage/${user.id}`}>

                <div
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    color: "blue",
                    textTransform: "initial"
                  }}
                  key={user.id}
                >
                  {user.name}
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))
          : null} </div> : null} </li>
    </ul>
    <div style={{marginTop: 100}}>*click on item to open submenu</div>
  </div>
)
```

In the new page , You can get the passed id using

```
 const params = useParams();
```

We will get the passed id from params.id, use componentdidmount to get the required data.